# Need assistance with an SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Here are the associated tables:

```
movie 
(
    mvnumb int, 
    mvtitle char(100), 
    yrmde int, 
    mvtype char(9), 
    crit int, 
    mpaa char(6), 
    noms int, 
    awrd int, 
    dirnumb int
)


director 
( 
    dirnumb int, 
    dirname char(36), 
    dirborn int, 
    dirdied int
)
```

My goal is to construct an SQL query that lists the name of the director who has received the maximum number of awards (awrd). I can't seem to get this to work ... any help would be greatly appreciated.. thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (SQL Server):

```
select top 1 d.dirname,sum(awrd) awrd
from director d
inner join movie m
on m.dirnumb=d.dirnumb
group by d.dirname
order by sum(awrd) desc
```

Or, on Oracle:

```
select * from (
select d.dirname, sum(awrd) awards
from director d
inner join movie m
on m.dirnumb=d.dirnumb
group by d.dirname
order by sum(awrd) desc )
where rownum<2;
```

EDIT: modified Oracle query, as @pilcrow suggested.

Comment: Not exactly sure, it's hosted on my school's network. I tried using TOP 1 earlier but that always results in:

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00935: group function is nested too deeply

When using the oracle code above.

Comment: @editThis, change the ORA to `select d.dirname, sum(awrd) awards`.  The fact that the `SUM` column is aliased as its source column is confounding `ORDER BY`.  This is a [feature](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:561712900346367451#2181298300346948018)